# Dlangui hello world program exit with non-zero code

Tags: d

I'm new to D and DlangUI, and I'm compiling a hello world app using  DlangUI following the [official wiki](https://github.com/buggins/dlangui/wiki/Getting-Started) using vscode, I have edited the app.d file and run `dub run`, it shows `Program exited with code -1073741701`.

I have tried the following but have no luck:

- `dub upgrade --force-remove`
- `dub build --force`
- remove dub.selections.json

Environment:

- dmd: v2.100.2-dirty
- dub: 1.29.2
- os: Windows 10 Professional 21H1 (64bit)

Output of `dub run`:

```
bindbc-loader 1.0.1: target for configuration "noBC" is up to date.
bindbc-opengl 1.0.2: target for configuration "dynamic" is up to date.
derelict-util 3.0.0-beta.2: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
derelict-ft 2.0.0-beta.5: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
derelict-sdl2 3.0.0-beta.8: target for configuration "derelict-sdl2-dynamic" is up to date.
inilike 1.2.1: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
isfreedesktop 0.1.1: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
xdgpaths 0.2.5: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
icontheme 1.2.3: target for configuration "library" is up to date.
dlangui 0.9.187: target for configuration "default" is up to date.
helloworld ~master: building configuration "application"...
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\src\dlangui\graphics\resources.d(104,8): Deprecation: module `std.xml` is deprecated - Will be removed from Phobos in 2.101.0. If you still need it, go to https://github.com/DigitalMars/undeaD
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\src\dlangui\widgets\styles.d(28,16): Deprecation: module `std.xml` is deprecated - Will be removed from Phobos in 2.101.0. If you still need it, go to https://github.com/DigitalMars/undeaD
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\3rdparty\dimage\png.d(585,1): Deprecation: Usage of the `body` keyword is deprecated. Use `do` instead.
Linking...
To force a rebuild of up-to-date targets, run again with --force.
Copying files for dlangui...
Running helloworld.exe
Program exited with code -1073741701
```

**Update #1:**

Seems that it's a 64 bit build, and now I try a 32 bit build using `dub build --arch=x86`(as the comments suggest) it shows something different:

```
Performing "debug" build using D:\env\dmd2\windows\bin\dmd.exe for x86, x86_mscoff.
bindbc-loader 1.0.1: building configuration "noBC"...
derelict-ft 2.0.0-beta.5: building configuration "library"...
derelict-sdl2 3.0.0-beta.8: building configuration "derelict-sdl2-dynamic"...
inilike 1.2.1: building configuration "library"...
isfreedesktop 0.1.1: building configuration "library"...
xdgpaths 0.2.5: building configuration "library"...
icontheme 1.2.3: building configuration "library"...
dlangui 0.9.187: building configuration "default"...
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\3rdparty\dimage\png.d(585,1): Deprecation: Usage of the `body` keyword is deprecated. Use `do` instead.
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\src\dlangui\graphics\resources.d(104,8): Deprecation: module `std.xml` is deprecated - Will be removed from Phobos in 2.101.0. If you still need it, go to https://github.com/DigitalMars/undeaD
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\src\dlangui\widgets\styles.d(28,16): Deprecation: module `std.xml` is deprecated - Will be removed from Phobos in 2.101.0. If you still need it, go to https://github.com/DigitalMars/undeaD
helloworld ~master: building configuration "application"...
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\src\dlangui\graphics\resources.d(104,8): Deprecation: module `std.xml` is deprecated - Will be removed from Phobos in 2.101.0. If you still need it, go to https://github.com/DigitalMars/undeaD
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\src\dlangui\widgets\styles.d(28,16): Deprecation: module `std.xml` is deprecated - Will be removed from Phobos in 2.101.0. If you still need it, go to https://github.com/DigitalMars/undeaD
C:\Users\JinReal\AppData\Local\dub\packages\dlangui-0.9.187\dlangui\3rdparty\dimage\png.d(585,1): Deprecation: Usage of the `body` keyword is deprecated. Use `do` instead.
Linking...
lld-link: error: unknown directive: EXETYPE
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

I've read this [post](https://github.com/buggins/dlangui/issues/597) and found that there's no `sourceFiles-windows` entry in it so it doesn't seem to be the same issue.

Comment: I think that code means missing dll... i don't know dlangui well but it might be that it requires sdl or something.

Comment: I just asked the new maintainer (he isn't on stack overflow) and he said: "I haven't tagged a new version after that. so, what I would suggest:
clone dlangui locally use "path" syntax in dub to choose the most recent version"

Comment: another possibility is you are doing a 32 bit build. hard to say since part part of the output isn't there, but you might want to try `dub build --arc=x86_64` to force a 64 bit thing and see what happens. or alternatively try 32 bit and see what happens

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Thanks, I'm trying and updating the post. Sorry I'm quite new to D, but what is path syntax in dub? is there any document about it?

Comment: Just heard back from the maintainer again: "oh, now I can reproduce
. can you ask the person to open an issue for dlangui? it's a bug. fix incoming" so sounds like not your fault. the path thing though is dub add path should be docs here https://dub.pm/commandline (personlly btw i don't use dub much nor dlangui so im just kinda middle manning here since im active on both stack overflow and the discord chat where the maintainer can be found)

Comment: Ok I've opened the issue in github(https://github.com/buggins/dlangui/issues/625), thanks so much for the help.